# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 ----Kindly help me solve it using Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'sudents_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `books` (`bookname`, `auther`, `cost`, `book_image`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Maths, Ali, 1000, 1613387802.png, 2021-02-15 11:16:43, 2021-02-15 11:16:43))

```
    public function create()
        {
            return view('books.create');
        }enter code here
    
        /**
         * Store a newly created resource in storage.
         *
         * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
         * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
         */
        public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $request->validate([
                'bookname' => 'required',
                'auther' => 'required',
                'cost' => 'required',
                'students_Id'=>'nullable',
                'book_image'=> 'required ',
            ]);
            
            $image=$request->file('book_image');
            $ext=$image->extension();
            $file=time().'.'.$ext;
            $image->storeAs('public/image',$file);
    
            $data=array(
                'bookname'=>$request->input('bookname'),
                'auther'=>$request->input('auther'),
                'cost'=>$request->input('cost'),
                'students_Id'=>$request->input('students_Id'),
                'book_image'=>$file,
                
            );
    
            Book::create($data);
         
            return redirect()->route('books.index')
                            ->with('success','Book added successfully.');
        }
```

Table schema:

```
     public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('bookname');
                $table->string('auther');
                $table->string('cost');
                $table->binary('book_image');
                $table->timestamps();
               /*  $table->bigIncrements('std_id');
                $table->foreign('std_id')
                    ->references('id')
                    ->on('students')
                    ->onDelete('cascade'); */
                $table->foreignId('sudents_id')->constrained('students');
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

was able to solve it changes in the code are as follow to solve the error:
Table Schema:

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('bookname');
            $table->string('auther');
            $table->string('cost');
            $table->binary('book_image');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('student_id');
            $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students');
           
        });
    }
```

also I add student_id in the Book Model

Create function in the BookController:

```
public function create()
    {
       $students = Student::all();
        return view('books.create',['students'=>$students]);
    }
```

store function in BookController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'bookname' => 'required',
            'auther' => 'required',
            'cost' => 'required',
            'student_Id'=>'nullable',
            'book_image'=> 'required ',
        ]);
        
        $image=$request->file('book_image');
        $ext=$image->extension();
        $file=time().'.'.$ext;
        $image->storeAs('public/image',$file);

        $data=array(
            'bookname'=>$request->input('bookname'),
            'auther'=>$request->input('auther'),
            'cost'=>$request->input('cost'),
            'student_Id'=>$request->input('student_id'),
            'book_image'=>$file,
            
        );

        Book::create($data);
     
        return redirect()->route('books.index')
                        ->with('success','Book added successfully.');
    }
```

for the Student Id to be viewed and slected use this code in the book create view:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>STUDENT</strong>
                <select name="student_id" id="" class="form-control">
                    @foreach ($students as $item)
                    <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->studname }}</option>
                        
                    @endforeach
                </select>
               
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a valid value in `students_id` field as the error stated. It is a foreign key value for the table `students` so the value you can insert should exists in that table. Hence you may need to set `students_id` by using `$request->input('students_Id', null)`.